# How to parse date with date.js

Tags: jquery, datejs

I'm trying to do a simple parse/calculation with some times, but dateJS does not seem to be working. I have the date.js file loaded in the EXACT same directory as my HMTL file, but my error console is saying the Date object does not have the property of parse(). Am I missing something?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
<script src="date.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 alert("hello");
 var future = new Date.parse("20:34:34");
 var now = new Date();
 var span = new TimeSpan(future - now);
 alert(span);
 alert("bye");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I corrected the code around parse but it still fails. My error console is now saying that TimeSpan is not defined...

And I pulled the datejs code off of their site TODAY.  Though the repo says it was last updated in 2007...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"parse" is a static method. You're using it as an instance method at the moment. Try changing:

```
Date().parse(..)
```

to

```
Date.parse(..)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that was only half of the battle.  I am getting an erro saying TimeSpan is not defined.

Comment: TimeSpan isn't defined within Date.js. It's not in their docs either. I do see a file called timespan that the datejs project uses internally, but if you want to use it, you'll need to include that source in your page as well.

Comment: Yes, `TimeSpan` is included in the `time.js` file. Add that file to your page, under `date.js` and your sample should work.